# How to understand the Url patterns in django url.py

Tags: django, django-urls, url-pattern

How to understand the Url patterns for eg. `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$` in django url.py

Comment: I was tempted to just recommend the [manual](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: It's a regular expression. Read up on http://docs.python.org/library/re.html to understand more.

Answer (score 4):

This url: `(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$`

Says that you are passing a variable to your view called `slug` could be any digits or letters and `-`

your view is like this:

```
def my_view(request, slug):
   ....
```

hope it helps...

Comment: This doesn't explain where those "digits or letters" come from.

Answer (score 0):

First [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/), then [7.2.1 - Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: Don't post just links as answers. Either add details / examples or post it as a comment.

Comment: I totally agree with agf even though the question of Gopi was not wise. Regular expressions is a huge field where just a link does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that slug fields might also include digits (not just letters and the dash), so you want to alter it to say something like:

```
 SLUG = '(?P<slug>[\w\d-]+)'
```

I hope this helpful to you...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He was asking how to interpret them, not how to change them to do something.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a valid regex pattern.
"[-\w]+" will get "word and -", something like "a-b9-c-" or "---"
(?P...) is a  "Named Group". If you don't give its name, python (mine is 2.7) will raise error.

```
>>> m = re.match("(?P<e>[-\w]+)/$", "a-b-c-/")
>>> m.group('e')
'a-b-c-'
>>> m = re.match("(?P[-\w]+)/$", "a-b-c-/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 137, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 244, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unknown specifier: ?P[
```

Comment: But it has the group specified. It *is* valid. (I presume you were looking at the non-escaped version which I fixed three-quarters of an hour before you posted this.)